# how to find cube root of 7 with Z3 library

Tags: python, z3, z3py

This code returns a good result but Does anyone have an idea how to convert this program to return the same result but in the Z3 solver???

```
from decimal import *
import time

getcontext().prec = 100
x = Decimal(7.0)

beg = time.time()
cuber = x**(Decimal(1)/Decimal(3))
end = time.time()
print(end-beg)
print(cuber)
```

Answer (score 0):

z3 doesn't come with a way to compute the cube-root directly, but you can express it using a simple constraint:

```py
from z3 import *

cuber = Real('cuber')

s = Solver()
s.add(cuber * cuber * cuber == 7)

if s.check() == sat:
    print(s.model())
else:
    print("Not satisfiable")
```

When run, this prints:

```
[cuber = 1.9129311827?]
```

That `?` at the end means this is an approximation, i.e., it's not the exact result. You can increase the print precision like this:

```py
set_param(precision=100)
```

(Add that line right after you `import` z3.) Now it'll print:

```
[cuber = 1.9129311827723891011991168395487602828624390503458757662106476404472342761792307560075254414772857099?]
```

which has more digits, but still not precise since cube-root of 7 is irrational.